# Blackbox exporter with probe to monitor external endpoints

Tags: prometheus-blackbox-exporter, probe, servicemonitor

I have installed blackbox exporter and prometheus using helm charts.
I want know how to monitor external endpoints using blackbox exporter and get the data to prometheus dashboard. How to do using servicemonitor and probe CRDs